# HammerJS v2 <div> with 'overflow-y: auto' does not scroll on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, touch, hammer.js

I have a page with HammerJS v2 on it. My layout looks like:

```
body - overflow: hidden
    div1 - overflow: hidden (this is always the size of the viewport)
        div2 - overflow-y: auto
    div1 - overflow: hidden (this is always the size of the viewport)
        div2 - overflow-y: auto
```

div2 shows a scrollbar when it has overflowed content, however, when trying to scroll on an iPad in safari or chrome, it doesn't work. On android devices it seems to work OK.

When you swipe on div1, it will take you to the next div1.

I have tried setting the hammer setting:

```
Hammer.defaults.touchAction = "pan-y";
```

But this starts allowing scrolling of the whole document, and I don't want that. I just want to scroll div2.

has anyone else came across this issue, or have any ideas what it could be?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve this? How?

Comment: Just submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting:

```
Hammer.defaults.touchAction = "compute";
```

I also had to put a pan event on div2's that mimic the scroll. I used the following article to help with mimicking the scroll: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/08/javascript-kinetic-scrolling-part-1.html